# Swift - best practice to find the longest string at [String] array

Tags: string, swift, sorting, max, maxlength

I'm trying to find what is the most effective way to get the longest string in a string array. For example :

```
let array = ["I'm Roi","I'm asking here","Game Of Thrones is just good"]
```

and the outcome will be - `"Game Of Thrones is just good"`

I've tried using the `maxElement` func, tho it's give the max string in a alphabetic ideas(`maxElement()`).

**Any suggestions? Thanks!**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Instead of sorting which is *O(n log(n))* for a good sort, use `max(by:)` which is *O(n)* on Array providing it a closure to compare string lengths:

**Swift 4:**

For Swift 4 you can get the string length with the `count` property on `String`:

```
let array = ["I'm Roi","I'm asking here","Game Of Thrones is just good"]

if let max = array.max(by: {$1.count > $0.count}) {
    print(max)
}
```

**Swift 3:**

Use `.characters.count` on `String` to get the string lengths:

```
let array = ["I'm Roi","I'm asking here","Game Of Thrones is just good"]

if let max = array.max(by: {$1.characters.count > $0.characters.count}) {
    print(max)
}
```

**Swift 2:**

Use `maxElement` on Array providing it a closure to compare string lengths:

```
let array = ["I'm Roi","I'm asking here","Game Of Thrones is just good"]

if let max = array.maxElement({$1.characters.count > $0.characters.count}) {
    print(max)
}
```

Note:  `maxElement` is *O(n)*. A good sort is *O(n log(n))*, so for large arrays, this will be much faster than sorting.

Comment: Thank you vaca! Much appreciate it - clean & elegant :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `reduce` to do this. It will iterate through your array, keeping track of the current longest string, and then return it when finished.

For example:

```
let array = ["I'm Roi","I'm asking here","Game Of Thrones is just good"]

if let longestString = array.reduce(Optional<String>.None, combine:{$0?.characters.count > $1.characters.count ? $0:$1}) {
    print(longestString) // "Game Of Thrones is just good"
}
```

<sup>(Note that `Optional.None` is now `Optional.none` in Swift 3)</sup>

This uses an `nil` starting value to account for the fact that the array could be empty, as pointed out by @JHZ (it will return `nil` in that case). If you know your array has at least one element, you can simplify it to:

```
let longestString = array.reduce("") {$0.characters.count > $1.characters.count ? $0:$1}
```

Because it only iterates through each element once, it will quicker than using `sort()`. I did a quick benchmark and `sort()` appears around 20x slower (although no point in premature optimisation, I feel it is worth mentioning).

---

**Edit:** I recommend you go with @vacawama's solution as it's even cleaner than `reduce`!

Comment: This algorithm is O(n).  A good sort is O(n log(n)), so for large arrays, this will be *much* faster.

Comment: I'd use `nil` as the initial value for reduce, and have it return an optional. The longest string in `[]` isn't `""`, it's nonexistent.

Comment: You are a real gentleman @originaluser2 . Thank you for your answer as well! upvoted :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
let array = ["I'm Roi","I'm asking here","Game Of Thrones is just good"]

var sortedArr = array.sort() { $0.characters.count > $1.characters.count }

let longestEelement = sortedArr[0]
```

Comment: Seems like a easier solution.

Comment: Use sortedArr.first instead of sortedArr[0] so longestElement is an Optional in case of an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also practice with the use of Generics by creating this function:

```
func longestString<T:Sequence>(from stringsArray: T) -> String where T.Iterator.Element == String{
    return (stringsArray.max {$0.count < $1.count}) ?? ""
}
```

Explanation: Create a function named longestString. Declar that there is a generic type T that implements the Sequence protocol (Sequence is defined here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence).  The function will return a single String (of course, the longest). The where clause explains that the generic type T should be limited to having elements of type String.

Inside the function, call the max function of the stringsArray by comparing the longest string of the elements inside.  What will be returned is the longest String (an optional as it can be nil if the array is empty). If the longest string is nil then (use of ??) returns an empty string as the longest string instead.

Now call it:

```
let longestA = longestString(from:["Shekinah", "Chesedh", "Agape Sophia"])
```

If you get the hang of using generics, even if the strings are hidden inside objects, you can make use of the pattern of coding above. You can change the element to objects of the same class (Person for example).

Thus:

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

func longestName<T:Sequence>(from stringsArray: T) -> String where T.Iterator.Element == Person{
    return (stringsArray.max {$0.name.count < $1.name.count})?.name ?? ""
}
```

Then call the function like these:

```
let longestB = longestName(from:[Person(name: "Shekinah"), Person(name: "Chesedh"), Person(name: "Agape Sophia")])
```

You also get to rename your function based on the appropriateness of its use. You can tweak the pattern to return something else, like the object itself, or the length (count) of the String. And finally, becoming familiar with generics may improve your coding ability.

Now, with a little tweak again, you may extend further so that you can compare strings owned by many different types as long as they implement a common protocol.

```
protocol Nameable {
    var name: String {get}
}
```

This defines a protocol named Nameable that requires those who implement to have a name variable of type String. Next, we define two different things that both implement the protocol.

```
class Person: Nameable {
    let name: String
    init(name: String){
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct Pet: Nameable {
    let name: String
}
```

Then we tweak our generic function so that it requires that the elements must conform to Nameable, vastly different though they are.

```
func longestName<T:Sequence>(from stringsArray: T) -> String where T.Iterator.Element == Nameable{
return (stringsArray.max {$0.name.count < $1.name.count})?.name ?? ""
}
```

Let's collect the different objects into an array. Then call our function.

```
let myFriends: [Nameable] = [Pet(name: "Bailey"), Person(name: "Agape Sophia")]

let longestC = longestName(from: myFriends)
```

Lastly, after knowing "where" above and "Sequence" above, you may simply extend Sequence:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String {

    func topString() -> String {
        self.max(by: { $0.count < $1.count }) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Or the protocol type:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Nameable {
    func theLongestName() -> Nameable? {
        self.max(by: { $0.name.count < $1.name.count })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The @vacawama is a good one, but one thing to consider is that you may have multiple elements of the same length. So the result of: "get the longest string in a string array" may be multiple Strings of the same long length. If that's the case, this may work:

```
if let max = array.max(by: {$1.count > $0.count}) {
    let largeStrings = array.filter{$0.count == max.count}
    print(largeStrings)
}
```